# MySQL LIMIT on DELETE statement

Tags: mysql, limit, sql-delete

I put together a test table for a error I recently came across. It involves the use of LIMIT when attempting to delete a single record from a MySQL table.

The error I speak of is "**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1**"

The table I put together is called *test*; it has 3 columns, *id*, *name* and *created*. I populated the table with several records and then attempted to delete one. Below is the statement I used to try and accomplish this.

`DELETE t FROM test t WHERE t.name = 'foo' LIMIT 1`

Without the use of LIMIT 1, the statement executes just fine, but of course I wouldn't be using LIMIT if there wasn't a need for it.

I'm fully aware that I can use another statement to accomplish this DELETE successfully. See below:
`DELETE FROM test WHERE name = 'foo' LIMIT 1`

However my question is centered on why the first statement isn't working with LIMIT.

So my question is, what I have done incorrectly with respect to the first statement to generate this error?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

the delete query only allows for modifiers  after the DELETE 'command' to tell the database what/how do handle things.

see [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html)

Comment: "However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT in a multiple-table DELETE".

This seems to answer my question.

Comment: yes - sorry didn't read that from the OP but what you say about deleting from a join is correct

Answer (score 40):

simply use

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE 1= 1 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he knows that this is working..."I'm fully aware that I can use another statement to accomplish this DELETE successfully.[...] `DELETE FROM test WHERE name = 'foo' LIMIT 1`"

Answer (score 14):

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html#idm45354680744576):

> You cannot use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` in a multiple-table `DELETE`.

Answer (score 6):

```
DELETE t.* FROM test t WHERE t.name = 'foo' LIMIT 1
```

@Andre If I understood what you are asking, I think the only thing missing is the t.* before `FROM`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround to solve this problem by using a derived table.

```
DELETE t1 FROM test t1 JOIN (SELECT t.id FROM test LIMIT 1) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Because the LIMIT is inside the derived table the join will match only 1 row and thus the query will delete only this row.

Comment: For a more complex query joining multiple tables, you need to repeat that complex query for the derived table, or else (in your example) the first id from test might not be in the delete condition, so no records will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_count - your_desired_offset`

So if we had 10 rows and want to offset 3

```
 10 - 3 = 7
```

Now the query `delete from table where this = that order asc limit 7` keeps the last 3, and  `order desc` to keep the first 3:

```
$row_count - $offset = $limit

Delete from table where entry = criteria order by ts asc limit $limit
```

Answer (score -1):

First I struggled a bit with a 
 DELETE FROM ... USING ... WHERE query,... 
Since i wanted to test first
so i tried with SELECT FROM ... USING... WHERE ... 
and this caused an error , ... 
Then i wanted to reduce the number of deletions adding
LIMIT 10 
which also produced an error
Then i removed the "LIMIT" and - hurray - it worked:
"1867 rows deleted. (Query took 1.3025 seconds.)"

The query was:

```
DELETE FROM tableX 
USING tableX , tableX as Dup 
WHERE NOT tableX .id = Dup.id 
 AND tableX .id > Dup.id 
 AND tableX .email= Dup.email 
 AND tableX .mobil = Dup.mobil
```

This worked.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because it's not an answer on the actual topic. Please see the question above.