# DELETE statement with ALIAS and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111961/mysql-limit-on-delete-statement), just a clean cut.

**Goal:**

I need to use a DELETE statement with ALIAS and LIMIT. Optionally with USING, WHERE, or anything else, other workarounds as long as it works.

Cases 4, 6, 7, 8 would potentially be the solution for this question, but each of them returns an ERROR.

Cases 1, 2, 3, and 5 are shown just for the sake of this example (to fill up the matrix if you will).

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int(10));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

#### 1) no alias, no limit - WORKS

```
DELETE FROM test;
```

#### 2) no alias, limit - WORKS

```
DELETE FROM test LIMIT 1;
```

#### 3) alias, no limit - ERROR

```
DELETE FROM test t;
```

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't' at line 2

#### 4) alias, limit (would be SOLUTION) - ERROR

```
DELETE FROM test t LIMIT 1;
```

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't LIMIT 1' at line 2

#### 5) alias+USING, no limit - WORKS

```
DELETE FROM t USING test t;
```

#### 6) alias+USING, limit (would be SOLUTION) - ERROR

```
DELETE FROM t USING test t LIMIT 1;
```

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 2

#### 7) alias, limit, where (would be SOLUTION) - ERROR

```
DELETE FROM test t WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 1;
```

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 1' at line 1

#### 8) alias+USING, limit, where (would be SOLUTION) - ERROR

```
DELETE FROM t USING test t WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 1;
```

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Try:  
DELETE FROM t USING test t where 2=2 LIMIT 1;

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL LIMIT on DELETE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111961/mysql-limit-on-delete-statement)

Comment: `DELETE t FROM test t...`

Comment: @EJP Nope, it's not. The OP's problem is with `USING` keyword

Comment: @i486 Your suggestion is already mentioned in the question. It can work though by using the trick EngineerCoder suggested.
`DELETE t FROM test t where 1=1 limit 1;`

Comment: Thank you EngineerCoder and alkis. Updated my post. However, still no luck. What am I doing rong?

Comment: A subquery is the standard SQL way to write this kind of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about this :

```
DELETE FROM t USING test t INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM test LIMIT 1) t2 ON t.id = t2.id
```