# LIMIT in DELETE in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
require_once '../class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();
$lstmtf = $user_home->runQuery("DELETE a FROM answer AS a LEFT JOIN students_records AS s ON a.ARN = s.ARN WHERE s.ARN IS NULL LIMIT 10");
$lstmtf->execute();
```

The **LIMIT** is not working, though it is not executing any query, I am not able to find my mistake.

**`UPDATE`**

I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111961/mysql-limit-on-delete-statement#comment7089450_6112042) helpful. So, now my question is:

There are many data which is to be deleted, but I want to delete in multiple ways(breaking the work). I am using:

```
require_once '../class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();
$lstmtf = $user_home->runQuery("DELETE a FROM answer AS a LEFT JOIN students_records AS s ON a.ARN = s.ARN WHERE s.ARN IS NULL LIMIT 10");
$lstmtf->execute();
```

But this query doesn't seem to execute the query properly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As a developer, it is unprofessional to say "not working". What doesnt work? what error(s) are thrown and what have you done to fix the issue(s)?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer why the query is not executing, removing `LIMIT 10` from the query executes the query.

Comment: I guess [this is the answer you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33238369/8913537)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I have just updated the question.